# Cloud build - gcloud compute ssh fails with profile size exceeds error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

In cloudbuild i am creating docker image.
Then i am deploying new image in Compute engine using `gcloud compute ssh --ssh-key-expire-after=2m --zone $_ZONE  $_GCE_NAME --tunnel-through-iap --project $PROJECT_ID --command={my commands to pull and deploy image}`

It was working well for few days, and started getting this error now a days.

*ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Login profile size exceeds 32 KiB*

**Solution Tried:**
https://github.com/kyma-project/test-infra/issues/93

This error is now being returned even if i create a new compute engine. Issue appears to be not with Compute Engine, it appears to be in cloud-build.

Comment: I think this caused the problem **--ssh-key-expire-after=2m**. Use the command `gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys list`. Then delete some of the keys.

Comment: @john-handley thank you for your response. Deleting --ssh-key-expire-after=2m has not resolved issue. Adding to it '''gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys list and delete ''' is executed for current user only. it is not possible to execute this command for cloudbuild service account inside Compute Engine as it is not possible to login as cloudbuild service account.  Just to test i created a complete new Compute Engine and this error is sent for new GCE as well which doesn't have any SSH Keys.

Comment: You can run the command as a job step. Review the output and create another step to delete keys or create a shell for loop to delete all keys as a job step.